# Print a variable output in a 400 empty message code using Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bad-request

#### Problem:

I am trying to code a bot for Discord so that to take a variable and send that as a message. For example, "a" is set to 42 and I want the bot to print in chat "The number is 42 {author name}":

```
a = 32

if message.content.startswith('!gap'):
    msg = print('a'.format(message))
    await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
```

#### Error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\trevo\Desktop\dcbot\reply.py", line 16, in on_message
    await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 1152, in send_message
    data = yield from self.http.send_message(channel_id, content, guild_id=guild_id, tts=tts, embed=embed)
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 200, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: BAD REQUEST (status code: 400): Cannot send an empty message
```

I appreciate explanations!

Comment: Are you aware that `'a'.format(message)` will just return `'a'`?

Comment: Yes, I realized that but right now I am just trying to use print as a message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expect `msg` to be a string, but if you try it:

```
>>> msg = print("anything at all")
>>> repr(msg)
None
```

Just remove the `print` call.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using the on_message event to make commands. Use the built-in command handler instead which makes for better program design and efficiency.

The following code outputs the number you type after **!gap**

```py
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def gap(ctx, number):
    await client.say(f"{ctx.author.mention} said the number {number}")

client.run("token")
```

I also recommend looking into the rewrite branch of the API which has a lot of improvements.